# Why doesn't a value become false using an if statement by calling a function on input?

Tags: javascript

When I typed some code to check if the password works when the user inputs the password. But I gave it the command to expire a password once it has been used. But it doesn't work. Why?

**My Code:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function checkPassword() {
      pass = true;
      if (document.querySelector(".input").value == "password" && pass == true) {
        alert("Password Works! Directing to Youtube...");
        location = "http://www.youtube.com";
        pass = false;
      } else if (pass == false) {
        alert("Password has Expired")
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Password:</h1>
  <input type="text" class="input" oninput="checkPassword()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are errors in the console when you use this. You probably meant `document.querySelector("input")` or `document.querySelector(".text")`

Comment: Also `pass1 = true;` is executed every time the `checkPassword` function is executed. So, it's *always* going to be reset to `true` before the check.

Comment: But how can I fix this?

Comment: Set the pass variable to true outside the scope of the function

Comment: That is, do `pass = true` just above the function

Comment: **NEVER use client-side code to check passwords! Anyone can bypass such a validation, and, even worse, can steal your secret password!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet of code, each time the input changes, the function checkPassword() is being called and then it is being returned. So essentially what happens is, everytime a function is called, the value of pass1 is true. So if you want to retain the value of pass1 on back to back calls of the function, then you can do something like this:-

```
<script>
    let pass1=true
    function checkPassword(){
        if (document.querySelector(".input").value == "password" && pass1 == true){
            alert("Password Works! Directing to Youtube...");
            location = "http://www.youtube.com";
            pass1 = false;
        } else if (pass1 == false){
            alert("Password has Expired")
        }
    }
</script>
```

But be aware that this is a lame solution and should be used for understanding purpose only. Everytime the page refreshes, the value of pass1 will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

well you can also use like this

```
<input type="text" name="password" oninput="checkPassword()">

if (document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value == "password" && pass == true)
```